# Android ListView onitemclick listener

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

when i click my list view item it calls onitemclick listener but when i click item long it calls both initemclick and onitemlongclick listeners. how to solve only call onitemlongclick listener when it long press?

```
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
           {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                //my code

            }


           });
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
//my code
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that, onItemLongClick() has a boolean return value. If you don't want onItemClick to be called, make onItemLongClick() to return true.

```
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
           //....

           // Above are your code.
           // Return true for this method as below.
           return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Such case better to use onClickListener() for individual views of the List instead of the list.
And also  for onItemLongClickListener() for the Views.

Answer (score 0):

Try using return like this...

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
           {

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {



        }


       });
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: where is the flag declaration

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return false to tell system that it shouldn't deliver the event any more.

```
  list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
              //Do something
              return false;
        }
```